# VueJS in Blade Template without Build Step

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I'm trying to implement VueJS in one of my pages blade template. I just want to use Vue in that single template.

I tried the following:

**default.blade.php**

```
//...
@yield('js-for-layout-before')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vue.min.js') }}"></script>
// ...
```

**view.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')
//...
@section('content')
    <div id="app">
    <ol>
        <todo-item></todo-item>
    </ol>
    <p>@{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="{{ asset('js/pages/vue_component.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

**vue_component.js**

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>This is a list item</li>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

With this, I am only getting a blank page. There are no errors in the console, all files are loaded.

The inspector shows what I mean:

[image]

I do not want to implement a build step or anything, just a minimum setup with vue. Any ideas what I am missing here?

--UPDATE:
I replaced vue.min.js with the development version and finally got a clue:

> vue.js:633 [Vue warn]: It seems you are using the standalone build of
>   Vue.js in an environment with Content Security Policy that prohibits
>   unsafe-eval. The template compiler cannot work in this environment.
>   Consider relaxing the policy to allow unsafe-eval or pre-compiling
>   your templates into render functions.

Comment: Any errors in the server console

Comment: No errors there either. @PatrickHollweck

Comment: Did you add the vue framework?

Comment: @Jerodev `vue.min.js` is added in the parent `default.blade.php`, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the issue was that my CSP didn't allow for `unsafe-eval`, which is required in this scenario without a build step. I didn't notice this until I included `vue.js` instead of the minified `vue.min.js`, which doesn't show errors.

To fix this for now, I did the following, though **you should probably not do this in production**: Check where your CSP is defined and add `'unsafe-eval'` to `"script-src"`.

In production, you probably want to use `nonce` on the script instead of `unsafe-eval` and something like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp to generate the `nonce`.